# Python syntax error on mad libs

Tags: python, syntax

So I'm trying to make a simple Mad Libs program and I'm getting multiple errors and I cannot figure out why. One of them is with the "Noah's First Program" part, and the other is with the printing of the story variable. How do I fix it?

```
print "Noah's First Program!"

name=raw_input("Enter a name:")
adjectiveone=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
adjectivetwo=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
adjectivethree=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
verbone=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
verbtwo=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
verbthree=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
nounone=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nountwo=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nounthree=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nounfour=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
animal=raw_input("Enter an Animal:")
food=raw_input("Enter a Food:")
fruit=raw_input("Enter a Fruit:")
number=raw_input("Enter a Number:")
superhero=raw_input("Enter a Superhero Name:")
country=raw_input("Enter a Country:")
dessert=raw_input("Enter a Dessert:")
year=raw_input("Enter a Year:")

STORY = “Man, I look really %s this morning. My name is %s, by the         way, and my favorite thing to do is %s. My best friend is super %s, because he owns a(n) %s and a(n) %s! What’s your favorite animal? Mine is a %s. I like to watch them at the zoo as I eat %s while %s. Those things are all great, but my other friend is even more interesting! She has a %s, and a lifetime supply of %s! She’s really %s, and her name is %s. She enjoys %s, but only %s times per day! She usually does it with %s. My favorite superhero is %s, but hers is %s. My third friend is named %s and is foreign. His family comes from %s, and their family name is %s. To wrap things up, my favorite dessert is %s, and I’m glad to have introduced you to my friends. Maybe soon I’ll introduce you to my fourth friend %s, but that will probably be in the year %s! I love %s!"

print STORY (adjectiveone,name,verbone,adjectivetwo,nounone,nountwo,animal,food,verbtwo,nounthree,fruit,adjectivethree,name,verbthree,number,name,superhero,superhero,name,country,name,dessert,name,year,nounfour)
```

Comment: What is the error message? What version of Python did you install?

Comment: Do you maybe need to escape the apostrophes?

Comment: I see curly quotes. Did you write part of this in Word or something?

Comment: I deleted the apostrophes and I'm running 2.7.11

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2, which `raw_input` leads me to believe, your code should be as follows:

```
print "Noah's First Program!"

name=raw_input("Enter a name:")
adjectiveone=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
adjectivetwo=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
adjectivethree=raw_input("Enter an Adjective:")
verbone=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
verbtwo=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
verbthree=raw_input("Enter a Verb:")
nounone=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nountwo=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nounthree=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
nounfour=raw_input("Enter a Noun:")
animal=raw_input("Enter an Animal:")
food=raw_input("Enter a Food:")
fruit=raw_input("Enter a Fruit:")
number=raw_input("Enter a Number:")
superhero=raw_input("Enter a Superhero Name:")
country=raw_input("Enter a Country:")
dessert=raw_input("Enter a Dessert:")
year=raw_input("Enter a Year:")

STORY = "Man, I look really %s this morning. My name is %s, by the way, and my favorite thing to do is %s. My best friend is super %s, because he owns a(n) %s and a(n) %s! What's your favorite animal? Mine is a %s. I like to watch them at the zoo as I eat %s while %s. Those things are all great, but my other friend is even more interesting! She has a %s, and a lifetime supply of %s! She's really %s, and her name is %s. She enjoys %s, but only %s times per day! She usually does it with %s. My favorite superhero is %s, but hers is %s. My third friend is named %s and is foreign. His family comes from %s, and their family name is %s. To wrap things up, my favorite dessert is %s, and I'm glad to have introduced you to my friends. Maybe soon I'll introduce you to my fourth friend %s, but that will probably be in the year %s! I love %s!"

print STORY % (adjectiveone,name,verbone,adjectivetwo,nounone,nountwo,animal,food,verbtwo,nounthree,fruit,adjectivethree,name,verbthree,number,name,superhero,superhero,name,country,name,dessert,name,year,nounfour)
```

To summarize:

Replace your apostrophes with `'`.

Fix your syntax for string formatting:

```
print STORY(arg1, ..., argn)
```

should be:

```
print STORY % (arg1, ..., argn)
```

If you are using Python 3, replace `raw_input` with `input` and `print ...` with `print(...)`. Also, according to [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should have a single space on either side of the `=` when assigning variables, so for example:

```
name=raw_input("Enter a name:")
```

should be:

```
name = raw_input("Enter a name:")
```

Though not doing it this way will not cause a syntax error.

Comment: Okay so thanks so much, this worked except it got a new error. This is what it displayed:Noah's First Program!
Enter a name: Noah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Noah/Desktop/Mad Libs 1.py", line 3, in <module>
    name=raw_input("Enter a name:")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: hmm...How are you running your script? Try opening a command line/terminal and entering: `python /Users/Noah/Desktop‌​/Mad\ Libs\ 1.py`. Also, it is best not to have spaces in script names. The usual Python way to name this script would be `madlibs.py` or `mad_libs.py`

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a Python 2.7 program.

But, if you use Python 2.7, you'll get syntax errors because `print` is not a statement but a function in Python 3: you need parenthesis.

Wrong:

```
print "Noah's First Program!"
```

Good:

```
print("Noah's First Program!")
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed this part but it's still having a syntax error on the print story aspect.

Comment: Missing comma after `STORY`: use `print(STORY, (adjectiveone, ...))`.